# MCU/Arduino RESET

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller, reset, arduino-uno

I have below setup. I found that My arduino Getting restarted again. I have Arduino board , lCD Display, SENSOR. The Sensor and LCD Display SHARE  common ground and 5v supply from 7805 IC and Arduino board get powered on using 7812 regulator IC . finally they are under common ground potential.Now i have Peice of code. Individually i tried each function are working fine without any error and Arduino Board will not get reseted.When i put together all my code block. getting restarted. Once it restart work fine for couple of minute and again reseted.

1. How to resolve this issue?

   ```
   #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
   #include <avr/wdt.h>
   LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 7, 6, 5, 4);
   void setup()
   {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);
    MODE=INIT;
    pinMode(beeper, OUTPUT);
    lcdClear();
   }

   void loop()
   {
   Track_loop();
   LCD_Display();
   CHK_Key();
   wdt_reset();
   Serial.println("..........................");
   }
   void Track_loop()
   {
     calcPos(); 
     calcTime();
     calcElevationAngle();
     callMode();
     actuate();
     // checkHWFaults();
     Wind_calc();
     Print_Result(); 

   }

   void Print_Result()
   {
     Print_Date();
     Print_Time();
   }
   ```

I have added these function in my Serial.println statement

```
void Print_Date(){
  Serial.print("Local Date:");
  Serial.print(local_day);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.print(local_month);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.println(local_year);
}
void Print_Time()
{ Serial.print("local_time is:");
  Serial.print(local_h);
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.print(local_m);
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.println(local_s);


}
```

Comment: Have you tried to figure out which piece it stalls at?

Comment: Is there any IDE availble for Arduino . Where i can use of break point.

Comment: @RKNAYAK if you do the Serial.println() at places you can then use a terminal program like Putty/Terraterm to connect over the Serial port and output those display commands

Comment: @wayne i could not able to understand what ur telling . can you elobrate the answer with example

Comment: @wayne i don't know how your answer related to above . use of Serial.println is only differentiate what we want to print on Serial monitor. How it could reset controller. I know when we close & open serial monitor board get reseted which can be avoid using capacitor between RESET and GND

Comment: @RKNAYAK - if you are using a cap I have added the UNO tag - otherwise you would be using resistor(s)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your use of the Watchdog is causing issues.

If we say that http://www.embedds.com/using-watchdog-timer-in-your-projects/ is an "authoritive" source of information, then maybe your call to wdt_reset() is not being called in time and therefore your system is being reset?

> If you enabled watchdog timer, you have to take care and reset it
>   before it fills up and resets MCU. Otherwise if your program hangs or
>   sticks in some infinite loop without reset watchdog simply counts up
>   and resets system

From [http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group_*avr*_watchdog.html](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__watchdog.html)

```
#define wdt_reset() __asm__ __volatile__ ("wdr")
```

> Reset the watchdog timer. When the watchdog timer is enabled, a call
>   to this instruction is required before the timer expires, otherwise a
>   watchdog-initiated device reset will occur.

If you disable the watchdog from your project, do you still get the same outcome?

**Update 1**

To debug your code you use the Serial.println("xxxx") function to output the required text to the serial port that you have setup.

See

- [Google Search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Using%20the%20Arduino%20serial%20monitor%20for%20debugging&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=Palemoon%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox&gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=8p4mU537B-3C8gfyjYDoCw&gws_rd=cr)
- [LadyAda Tutorial](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/lesson4.html)
- Countless others

NOTE: Should we update these instructions so that they contain the full instructions? Marking as Community Wiki so everyone can update as required.

Comment: Initially i Found that watch dog might reseting it , But i removed watchdog timer instruction and run the program . Eventhough it is giving same problem

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to clarify. as i understood i don't have added any  **Serial.println("xxxx")** in between of statement. I wanted to know why it is being reseted again and again

Comment: @RKNAYAK - I am not saying Serial.println() is the problem. It will help diagnose where the problem exists. Say you have println("A"), println("B") and println("C"). If you attach to the port an only see A/B outputted, then you know that the problem exists in the instructions before the println("C"). What I would do is put a println("Entering xxx") and println("Leaving xxx") in your subroutines to identify which one is causing the reset

Comment: ya thanks i solved some problem.  put break point as you mentioned. I found the Serial.print defined inside my function leading problem to  reset.But it don't make any sense, why i cant i use a Serial print in any function.once i removed all Serial.println statement from the loop getting started working

Comment: @RKNAYAK - it maybe because serial.println uses to much clock time that the watchdog kicks in before it outputs all the bytes. Unless required i use a DEBUG #def and wrap my println. That way I can run optimised code when doing testing on the hardware